# Difficulty installing PHP from source to CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos, php, source

**The problem:**

After installing PHP from source, functionality is not present - my phpinfo test page does not work. If I use yum to install from the repository functionality is restored.

**Why am I doing this:**

Ultimately I want to add ImageMagick/MagickWand funcationality. Appearently MagickWand needs to be compiled with PHP and sources I've found stating otherwise have been unsuccessful for me.

**What I've tried:**

About every resource I've found is fairly straight-forward but nothing really addresses what to do if this process fails:

1. Get your desired distribution. I've tried the latest (5.5.1) and what is in the CentOS repository (5.3.3)
2. Get prerequsits - most reference libxml2-devel, some httpd-devel and gcc.
3. ./configure --with content specific to your build (varies)
4. make && make install
5. place php.ini from source folder into /etc/
6. restart httpd.

**A couple examples of documents I've observed for this process:**

http://benramsey.com/blog/2012/03/build-php-54-on-centos-62/
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/instruction-guide-to-install-php5-from-source-on-linux/

**Im not sure what I'm doing wrong** but honestly I don't work from source very often. I feel that I am missing an unwritten constant. Any advice? I'll be able to provide any additional information as needed.

Comment: [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) has everything you need precompiled and ready to install with `yum`.

Comment: epel does not have a php-5.5

Comment: @ALex_hha: I am not sure 5.5 was a requirement. And unless it's  required, you are better of with replacing as few items as possible from your stock distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very bad practice to install from source. All you need is to install [IUS Community Repo](http://iuscommunity.org/pages/About.html)

*excerpt*

> The IUS Community Project is aimed at providing up to date and
>   regularly maintained RPM packages for the latest upstream versions of
>   PHP, Python, MySQL and other common software specifically for Redhat
>   Enterprise Linux. IUS can be thought of as a better way to upgrade
>   RHEL, when you need to.

You can add the repo as follows to `yum`:

```
# rpm --import http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/IUS-COMMUNITY-GPG-KEY

# rpm -ivh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-11.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
```

And then install necessary packages

```
# yum search --enablerepo=ius-testing php55u
php55u-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package php55u
php55u.x86_64 : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
php55u-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath library
php55u-cli.x86_64 : Command-line interface for PHP
php55u-common.x86_64 : Common files for PHP
php55u-dba.x86_64 : A database abstraction layer module for PHP applications
php55u-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php55u-embedded.x86_64 : PHP library for embedding in applications
php55u-enchant.x86_64 : Human Language and Character Encoding Support
php55u-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php55u-gd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the gd graphics library
php55u-gmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the GNU MP library
php55u-imap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use IMAP
php55u-interbase.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use Interbase/Firebird databases
php55u-intl.x86_64 : Internationalization extension for PHP applications
php55u-ldap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use LDAP
php55u-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
php55u-mcrypt.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides mcrypt library support
php55u-mssql.x86_64 : MSSQL database module for PHP
php55u-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php55u-odbc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use ODBC databases
php55u-opcache.x86_64 : The Zend OPcache
php55u-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications
php55u-pear.noarch : PHP Extension and Application Repository framework
php55u-pgsql.x86_64 : A PostgreSQL database module for PHP
php55u-process.x86_64 : Modules for PHP script using system process interfaces
php55u-pspell.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using pspell interfaces
php55u-recode.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the recode library
php55u-snmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that query SNMP-managed devices
php55u-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php55u-tidy.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides tidy library support
php55u-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php55u-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was far more helpful than any of the resources telling me to configure from the source. I saw Imagick was available and was easily on my way.