# How to reconfigure PHP

Tags: centos, php, mysql, configure, reinstall

We have a new linux server CentOS 6.5 with Plesk. Default PHP is 5.3.3, I have  installed PHP5.4 & 5.5 on the server.

I have to install PHP by using this [guide](http://alexbouma.me/multiple-php-versions-for-plesk-11-5/)

PHP installed successfully but some functions do not work, such as mysqli.

Default PHP 5.3.3 configure command is:

`--with-mysql=shared,/usr --with-mysqli=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config`

but my installed PHP 5.4 configure command is:

`--with-mysql=/usr --with-mysqli`

I think something is missing.

I want to know how to restore mysqli features?

Answer (score 0):

You can get PHP 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5 from IUS repos:
https://iuscommunity.org/

There are detailed instructions on how to set this up here:
[Difficulty installing PHP from source to CentOS 6.4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84564/difficulty-installing-php-from-source-to-centos-6-4#84565)