# installing php-mysql on rhel6

Tags: php, mysql

I have rhel6 running on my server and installed mysql from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 / Oracle Linux 6 (x86, 64-bit), RPM Bundle. Now I want to host a php site on that machine. And when I run `yum install php-mysql` it throws me an bunch of conflicting files that looks like

`file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64`

How can I install php-mysql on my server without removing my installed mysql

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're installing MySQL from mysql.org and attempting to use stock PHP from RHEL6 with it. My advice is to stick to one distribution source for packages that are related/built off each other. In other words, RHEL6 PHP packages expect RHEL6 MySQL counterparts and vice versa.

If you really need recent PHP/MySQL builds on CentOS/RHEL, I suggest the following:
[Difficulty installing PHP from source to CentOS 6.4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84564/difficulty-installing-php-from-source-to-centos-6-4#84565)
This will let you install modern PHP and MySQL releases that will work with each other.

Comment: I don't want to install php. I just want to make it work with mysql